# Default apt-get language change

Tags: linux, ubuntu, locale, texmaker

My default language in Linux is English.

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IN.UTF-8"
```

However, when I try to install texmaker I get Spanish options instead of English.
What is the mistake I'm doing?
i install texmaker using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install texmaker
```

Any help will be appreciated
Not sure if this is the correct place for this question. please redirect if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It work for switching between Russian and English locale. I haven't installed Spanish locale and can't test solution. But I hope below can work for you:

```
$ LANG=ru_UA.utf8 #Replace ru_UA to your Spanish (es-US or es-ES) locale here.
$ sudo apt-get install texmaker #After run it you get message on desired language
$ LANG=en_EN.utf8 #Return old locale
```

Comment: Why would I want to change my default language to Russian? Can you please give some explanation there.

Comment: @pistal OP did the same, but with Russian locale. He is not entirely sure, that doing the same with Spanish will work by you, and he can't test it, because his systems have no Spanish locale. So, he explained what he did with Russian, and suggest you to do the same with Spanish. While the OP is not, I am sure, that it would work (locales are very well standardized on *nixes).

Comment: By me LANG is en_IL.UTF-8 and I get apt prints in French...